# Syntax error in matching keys from HashiCorp Vault with awk

Tags: bash, awk, vault

I am getting this syntax error with trying to capture both the unseal key and the root token from HashiCorp Vault secrets

```
vault operator init -recovery-shares=1 -recovery-threshold=1 | tee /etc/vault/vault-init.txt
unseal_key=$(awk '{ if (match($0,/Recovery Key 1: (.*)/,m)) print m[1] }' /etc/vault/vault-init.txt)
root_token=$(awk '{ if (match($0,/Initial Root Token: (.*)/,m)) print m[1] }' /etc/vault/vault-init.txt)
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
```

This is a sample Vault ket set:

```
 cat /etc/vault/vault-init.txt
Recovery Key 1: qUGxg+3RxX2AU0/SRDl1XxuA1iUWd650Ns3m1MGsDuk=

Initial Root Token: s.fXUGB0hS6VHWg4CaG5EMcRgh

Success! Vault is initialized
```

What is wrong with my `awk` statements?

Comment: Your code works for me (Linux Mint 20), gnu awk 5.0.1....?

Comment: this code works for me (GNU awk 5.1.1); what is your `awk` version (`awk --version`)?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the 3rd arg to `match()` but your awk version doesn't support it. Install a recent version of GNU awk if you want that functionality. One alternative with any awk given the sample input you provided is:

```
$ awk '/Recovery Key 1: /{print $NF}' file
qUGxg+3RxX2AU0/SRDl1XxuA1iUWd650Ns3m1MGsDuk=

$ awk '/Initial Root Token: /{print $NF}' file
s.fXUGB0hS6VHWg4CaG5EMcRgh
```